# python configparser hangs silently

Tags: python, configparser

I have a feeling I'm being stupid.  Given this ini file:

```
[main]
source1 = ./testing/sdir1
sync1 = ./testing/sydir1
archive1 = ./testing/adir1
source2 = ./testing/sdir2
sync2 = ./testing/sydir2
archive2 = ./testing/adir2
[logging]
log_dir = .
log_file = pixelsync.log
log_level = DEBUG
```

The following code hangs:

```
import ConfigParser

CONFIG_FILE = 'pixelsync.ini'

def parse_config() :
    """read details from the config file"""
    global CONFIG_FILE
    config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    config.read(CONFIG_FILE)
    index = 1
    while True :
        if config.has_option('main', 'source' + str(index)) and \
                    config.has_option('main', 'sync' + str(index)) and \
                    config.has_option('main', 'archive' + str(index)) :

            result = ( config.get('main', 'source' + str(index)),
                       config.get('main', 'sync' + str(index)),
                       config.get('main', 'archive' + str(index)))
            index += 1
        else :
            if index == 1 :
                print "could not setup any trios from the config file. exiting."
                sys.exit(1)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    options = parse_config()
```

It hangs on the 'if' clause.

If I replace the 'if' clause with :

```
if config.has_option('main', 'source1' ) and \
                    config.has_option('main', 'sync1' ) and \
                    config.has_option('main', 'archive1' ) :
```

it doesn't hang.  (doesn't do what I want since I need to loop through an arbitrary number of sets of three, but it doesn't silently hang.

Python v2.7.3 on ubuntu 12.04 (Precise), 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your program hangs is it never breaks out of the loop - it goes on forever. Rather than simply setting `result`, you need to `return` it. (An alternative is to set it and then use `break` to break out of the loop and return, but that is somewhat roundabout. It's better to simply return it straight away.

Note that doing `while True:` and counting like that isn't very Pythonic, the preferred approach is to instead use [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

E.g:

```
import itertools

...

for index in itertools.count(1):
    ...
```

Note that this shows a design flaw. You probably want to have a way of knowing if you are never going to get a suitable result. Infinite loops are generally bad.

Comment: ok. Thanks for pointing out the stupid.
I blame the 2 hours of sleep from last night.

Comment: I was leaving out the 'else : break' from the inner if statement.